# Marca dágua upload de imagem em codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, upload

Olá! Estou tentando inserir marca d'água ao cadastrar a imagem, porém a imagem é upada, só que não insere a marca d'água e nem retorna erros, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Segue código abaixo:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $field => $file) {
        if ($file['error'] == 0) {
            if ($this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $dados['imagem'] = $data['file_name'];       

                $img_config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
                $img_config['wm_overlay_path'] = PATH_FRONT_END_UPLOAD.'usuarios/logo.png';
                $img_config['wm_x_transp'] = 20;
                $img_config['wm_y_transp'] = 10;
                $img_config['wm_opacity'] = 50;
                $img_config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
                $img_config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
                $config['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];  
                $this->image_lib->watermark();
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
            } else {
                $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                die($errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde.
Eu tive um problema parecido com a geração de thumbnails.
A solução foi carregar a lib fora do `foreach` e a cada nova configuração parametrizada, usei o seguinte código:

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Oss

Atualizado:
Tenta com o seguinte código:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $field => $file) {
        if ($file['error'] == 0) {
            if ($this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $dados['imagem'] = $data['file_name'];       

                $img_config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
                $img_config['wm_overlay_path'] = PATH_FRONT_END_UPLOAD.'usuarios/logo.png';
                $img_config['wm_x_transp'] = 20;
                $img_config['wm_y_transp'] = 10;
                $img_config['wm_opacity'] = 50;
                $img_config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
                $img_config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
                $config['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];  
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->image_lib->initialize($img_config);                 
                $this->image_lib->watermark();

            } else {
                $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                die($errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Olá! Tentei inserir as libs antes do foreach, porém também não funcionou :( atualizei o código e removi o código para inserção de thumbs, pois não preciso de thumbs no momento, assim o código fica bem menor e mais facil de entender.

Comment: Atualizado, tenta com o código que eu refatorei a partir do teu... Oss